# Access Database-linked forms not working after Server Reboot

Tags: error, database, microsoft-access

Our server went down & when I rebooted, all is working on site except Access Database-linked forms are not working.

It is showing following error:

```
> Preparing Site ...  Someone has recently made changes to this site and
> the site is being updated. If the site remains offline for an extended
> period of time, contact a site owner.  Wait a moment and refresh your
> browser
```

Nothing happens further.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try checking the ULS logs at the time you're accessing the site - you might get more information out of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves mine

1. Create a Access Service Application
   (Central Administration –-> Manage Service Applications –-> New –-> Access Services)
2. Started the Access Database Service
   (Central Administration –-> Manage Services on Server)

Now open the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell and enter:

> enable-spSessionStateService –DataBaseName

This creates a session state database and turns on the session state service.

Source: Googling